# The specific verb for covering a floor surface with parquets / moquette / carpet on the ground

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

What is the verb used for the noun **parquet** and **moquette** and **carpet** in order to cover a floor surface using them?

I.e. I have no idea whether you'd use them in the following ways:

> - We have laid parquets all over the house.
> - You'd better lay parquet / moquette all your apartment.

Unfortunately, my dictionaries couldn't give me any hint in this regard! I have my doubts whether the nouns play a verb role too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [*carpet*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carpet) and [*parquet*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parquet) *can* be used as verbs.

As in:

> I *carpeted* the floor.
>   I *parqueted* the floor.

*Moquette* has no such verbal equivalent. (Although if you used it that way, I doubt you'd be misunderstood—so long as the other person knew what *moquette* was; it's something I'd never heard of before just now.)

But there is certainly nothing wrong with using the verbs *lay* or *cover* with one of those nouns.